# Group by issue in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to group my records without aggregate function. I have tried so far but does not work.

```
select   c.CustomerName, c.CustAddress, c.Phone,o.OrderDate,s.CreditEndDate 
from customer c 
inner join Orders o on c.ID=o.CustomerID
inner join Sales s on s.OrderID = o.OrderNum   
group by c.CustomerName
```

Because the data needs to be grouped:(Before group by)

```
+---------+----------+------+------------+------------+
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2014-06-19 | 2015-09-05 |
+---------+----------+------+------------+------------+
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2014-06-19 | 2015-09-07 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-07 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-07 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-09 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-09 | 2015-09-07 |
| onetime | xx       | xx   | 2015-09-07 | 2015-09-07 |
| onetime | xx       | xx   | 2015-09-07 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-09 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-09 | 2015-09-07 |
| Jemila  | Salimiya | +96  | 2015-09-09 | 2015-09-07 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-08 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-08 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-08 |
| Halima  | Tegbared | 0917 | 2015-09-05 | 2015-09-08 |
+---------+----------+------+------------+------------+
```

Any help? Thanks in Advance.

it shows error

> > Column 'customer.CustAddress' is invalid in the select list because it
> >     is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
> >     clause.

In this case I don't need any aggregate function just grouping the same record into one row.

Comment: because you gave no instruction which  c.CustAddress, c.Phone,o.OrderDate,s.CreditEndDate you expect

Comment: You're selecting 5 non-aggregate columns but only grouping by one of them. You can't do that. It will try to group by `CustomerName`, but you've never told it what to do with `CustAddress`, `Phone`, `OrderDate`, `CreditEndDate`.

Comment: Thank you for useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `group by` clause is usually used with one or more aggregate function such as `sum()` or `count()` etc.

The only time when it can be used without an aggregate function is when you don't want to duplicate values in the result set, which is equivalent to using `DISTINCT` keywork. In this case, you need to include all columns in the select statement in the `group by`.